# Getting compilation error while trying to get const_iterator to find the element exist in the set or not

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <class T>
Node<T>* LinkedList<T>::findCommonNode_hash(LinkedList<T>* list_2)

{

         unordered_set<Node<T>*>* set = new unordered_set<Node<T>*>();
         Node<T>* curr_list_1 = head->next;
         Node<T>* curr_list_2 = list_2->head->next;
         unordered_set<Node<T>*>::const_iterator itr = set->find(curr_list_1);
         if(itr == set->end())
         {
             set->insert(curr_list_1);
         }
         else
            return curr_list_1;
         unordered_set<Node<T>*>::const_iterator itr1 = set->find(curr_list_2);
         if((itr1 == set->end()))
         {
             set->insert(curr_list_2);
         }
         else
            return curr_list_2;
         return nullptr;
}
```

IDE: codeblock C++11 .
I am getting the below error when trying to get the const_iterator to find the element exist in the set or not.

```
 C:\Education\DataStructure_Algorithms\List\List.cpp|252|
error: need 'typename' before 'std::unordered_set<Node<T>*>::
const_iterator' because 'std::unordered_set<Node<T>*>' is a dependent scope|
```

Comment: You have tow if-else, the second if-self is never executed. Why do you want to do with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests you have to add `typename` keyword because `const_iterator` is a dependent name in this case.

Like this:

```
typename unordered_set<Node<T>*>::const_iterator itr = set->find(curr_list_1);
```

And of course the same for the other similar line.

Anyway your code doesn't really seem to make any sense, but I guess that's because it's just work in progress.